# facebook login with firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, facebook-login

I am using facebook login and firebase together.
I got this error from facebook.

does firebase not meet these standards
what can i do about it.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/datasecurity

Platform Terms 6.a.i.1: You must always have in effect and maintain administrative, physical, and technical safeguards that do the following: Meet or exceed industry standards given the sensitivity of the Platform Data

Comment: I have the same error do you figured out where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Auth with Facebook is a violation of Facebook Policies.

I have also just been notified by facebook of this policy violation,when I also integrated firebase.

Please see this link for more information: [FirebaseAuth With Facebook](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/626)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30176711)